# How to denote two UL lists as two different items in parent container for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I feel like I'm missing something conceptually between parent/child(items) in FlexBox.

I'm looking to create a NavBar that looks like this:

**Desired output:**

```
Logo      Home Store(class "leftbar")      About Search Contact Button(class "rightbar")
```

```html
 <header>
    <img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/bootstrap-logo-3C30FB2A16-seeklogo.com.png" alt="bootstraplogo" class="boostraplogo">
    <nav>
      <ul class="leftbar">
        <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Documentation</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Examples</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Icons</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Themes</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Expo</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Blog</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="rightbar">
        <li>v4.5</li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/github.svg" alt="github"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/slack.svg" alt="slack"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/bootstrap-clone/Images/google.svg" alt="google"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><button>Download</button></a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </nav>


  </header>
```

My attempted solution:

```css
header {
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
  };
```

Issue is that this is the output from the CSS code above aggregates the UL list together when I use  **justify-content: space-evenly;** so it becomes

Logo ............ Home Store About Search Contact Button

Comment: You apply flex to header, but the 2 ul are inside nav, which is not flex.

Comment: Gotcha to really nail this home - so Nav is the child element of header?

Answer (score 0):

Flex only applies to child elements, not the whole descendant tree. I'd move the logo inside `nav` and apply flex there.

```css
header nav {
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  background: pink; <!-- demo only -->
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="bootstraplogo" class="boostraplogo">

    <ul class="leftbar">
      <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Documentation</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Examples</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Icons</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Themes</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Expo</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Blog</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="rightbar">
      <li>v4.5</li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="github"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="twitter"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="slack"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="google"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><button>Download</button></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `flex` only applies to `<header>` but you want `<img>` and the 2 `<ul>`s to flex. So I would eliminate the `<nav>`.

```html
<header>
    <img src="..." alt="bootstraplogo" class="boostraplogo">
    <ul class="leftbar">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rightbar">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

By the way, don't add a `;` after your CSS block.

```css
header {
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
} /* no ; here */
```